# How to send error message from C# to Ajax to use this error message's content in client side?

Tags: c#

I am currently working to send error C# message to Ajax. In C# I have implemented manager and controller,It works fine. Now my purpose to send error messages to user. User should see error-info message client side, this error messages pop-up has "ok" and "cancel". I had implemented this pop-up function. The problem is that How can I send this error from C# controller

I added Throw Exception in C# manager , I can see error pop up in client side automatically without handling this error.

**C# Controller**

```
[HttpPatch]
[CatchException]
public IHttpActionResult ChangePositioningPlan(ChangePositioningPlan changeCommand)
    {
        changePositioingPlan.Process(changeCommand);
        return Ok("true");
    }
```

**C# Manager**

```
public void Process(ChangePositioningPlan command)
    {
        if (!command.Ids.Any())
        {
            throw new Exception("Please select Position Plan Template.");
        }
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var positioningPlanId in command.Ids)
        {
            var positioningPlanToChange = positioningPlanRepository.FindBy(positioningPlanId);

            positioningPlanToChange.ShippingSerieses.Clear();
            string[] shippingIds = Array.ConvertAll(command.ShippingIds[i].Split(','), p => p.Trim());
            var list = new List<ShippingSeries>();
            foreach (var shippingId in shippingIds)
            {

                var existingShippingId = shippingSeriesRepository.FilterBy(sid => shippingId == sid.ShippingId).FirstOrDefault();
                if (existingShippingId == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException($"Shipping Id={shippingId} is not found.");
                }
                list.Add(existingShippingId);

                var checkExistingDateWithOtherPlanIds = positioningPlanRepository.FilterBy(d =>
                    positioningPlanToChange.DeliveryDate == d.DeliveryDate).ToList();
                //var test = checkExistingDateWithOtherPlanId.ShippingSerieses.Contains(existingShippingId);
                foreach (var existingPlanId in checkExistingDateWithOtherPlanIds)
                {
                    var checkPlanId = existingPlanId.ShippingSerieses.Contains(existingShippingId);
                    if (checkPlanId)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException($"Shipping Id Has already assigned to PlanId:" +
                                                    $"Shipping ID -> Plan ID " +
                                                    $"{existingShippingId.ShippingId} -> {existingPlanId.PlanId}, {positioningPlanToChange.PlanId}");
                    }

                }                  
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, based on your feedback, let's take another (cleaner) shot at this. Try something like this:

```
public class ChangePositioningPlan
{
    public bool SomePropertyMissing { get; set; }
    public bool SomeOtherPropertyMissing { get; set; }
}

//This is your Manager class
public class SomeObject : ActionResult
{
    private ChangePositioningPlan _command;
    public SomeObject(ChangePositioningPlan command)
    {
        _command = command;
        _command.SomePropertyMissing = true; //Error 
    }
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (_command.SomePropertyMissing)
        {
            context.HttpContext.AddError(new ArgumentException("GetFeedback: Something was not found!"));
            return; //Whether you want to return or continue execution?
        }
        if (_command.SomeOtherPropertyMissing)
        {
            context.HttpContext.AddError(new Exception("ShowInfo: Something else was not found!"));
            return; //Whether you want to return or continue execution?
        }
    }
}
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(ChangePositioningPlan command)
    {
        return new SomeObject(command);
    }
}
```

Then you can just see if the response message contains GetFeedback or ShowInfo, filter that out and display your error to your users.

There could be potential for improving this and removing "ShowInfo" and "GetFeedback", but I can't come up with something. Maybe try asking another question that specifically addresses this.

Comment: I did your changes but I get error : `CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult' to 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult'.`

Comment: Sorry about that, just change the return type of your Action to ActionResult (instead of IHttpActionResult)

Comment: If I change return type to ActionResult, then try part is not correct but catch part is ok , because try part return boolean ,

Comment: Ok, for status code OK (200) you can do the same as with status code 500, just pass whatever data you have along (instead of the error message for status 500).

Comment: thanks for clarification , but If I have more than throw exception in C# manager, then all of them will be seen in 500 code , am I correct? how can I separate exceptions in controller, how can I know which error is which ?

Comment: You could combine this answer with the one of Midhun and create a class that holds a response (ResponseModel). Then you could define an enum property (for example, ErrorSource) where you define your custom errors. Something like that. Then you could do ErrorSource = ErrorSource.MissingShippingId.

Comment: Why do you need to know where the error comes from in your controller  if I may ask?

Comment: Sorry, It is important for client side .Because I have 3 exceptions in manager , while I sending exception to client side, I should know which error is.For 2 erorrs of them  I just show info pop , and user has nothing to do , but one error is important for me , because I show error pop and , if this error happens user may be select ok button then send some info to database.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps

1. Create a class as below as the response model for the api.

   ```
   public class ResponseModel
   {
       /// <summary>
       ///  Gets or sets a value indicating whether Success or not
       /// </summary>
       public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }

       /// <summary>
       /// Gets or sets Error Message
       /// </summary>
       public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   2.Modify your method as follwos that return the response model instead of the void.

**C# Manager**

```
 public ResponseModel Process(ChangePositioningPlan command)
    {
        try
        {
            // your current method code
            ResponseModel response = new ResponseModel();
            response.IsSuccess = true;
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ResponseModel response = new ResponseModel();
            response.IsSuccess = false;
            response.ErrorMessage = "Your error message to show";
            return response;
        }
    }
```

**C# Controller**

3.Retutn the response instead of "true"

```
[HttpPatch]
[CatchException]
public IHttpActionResult ChangePositioningPlan(ChangePositioningPlan changeCommand)
{
    return Ok(changePositioingPlan.Process(changeCommand));
}
```

4.In front end read the response and

```
var response =  received_reponse;

    if(response.IsSuccess == false)
    {
       var errormsg=response.ErrorMessage ;
      //show pop up and display error message
    }
```